# Missing Rating collection after altering query

Tags: collection, query

In the review list I've altered the sort based on a custom table.

in *app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/review/product/view/list.phtml*

I've altered

```
$_items = $this->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();
```

Into

```
/** @var Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review_Collection $collection */
$collection = $this->getReviewsCollection();
$collection->clear();
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft( array('featured'=>'review_featured'), 'main_table.review_id = featured.review_id', array('featured.featured_number'));
$collection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
$collection->getSelect()->order('featured.featured_number DESC');
$_items = $collection->getItems();
```

But now the rationg collection is `null`

```
/* @var Mage_Rating_Model_Resource_Rating_Option_Vote_Collection $_votes */
$_votes = $_review->getRatingVotes();
```

How Do I alter the query and keep my collection?

Comment: Don't do this in the template. Rewrite the block and reimplement getReviewCollection().

Comment: Hi @Melvyn that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Melvyn suggested in the comments, implementing it in the Block class worked. Not totally sure why and how, but it works.

```
<?php

class Namespac_Module_Block_Product_View_List extends Mage_Review_Block_Product_View_List {

    public function getReviewsCollection()
    {
        if (null === $this->_reviewsCollection) {
            $this->_reviewsCollection = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
                ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addEntityFilter('product', $this->getProduct()->getId());

            $this->_reviewsCollection->clear();
            $this->_reviewsCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft( array('featured'=>'review_featured'), 'main_table.review_id = featured.review_id', array('featured.featured_number'));
            $this->_reviewsCollection->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
            $this->_reviewsCollection->getSelect()->order('featured.featured_number DESC');

        }
        return $this->_reviewsCollection;
    }
```

}